# Single click edit in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, xaml

I want the user to be able to put the cell into editing mode and highlight the row the cell is contained in with a single click. By default, this is double click.

How do I override or implement this?

Comment: Are you using the DataGrid found within the WPF Toolkit?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give us a little more information on what you have tried and how it doesn't work?

Answer (score 82):

Here is how I resolved this issue:

```
<DataGrid DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridCell_Selected" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemView}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This DataGrid is bound to a CollectionViewSource (Containing dummy **Person** objects).

The magic happens there : **DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridCell_Selected"**.

I simply hook the Selected Event of the DataGrid cell, and call BeginEdit() on the DataGrid.

Here is the code behind for the event handler :

```
private void DataGridCell_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Lookup for the source to be DataGridCell
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
    {
        // Starts the Edit on the row;
        DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
        grd.BeginEdit(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get around the already-selected row problem by setting the `SelectionUnit` property on the DataGrid to `Cell`.

Comment: Suppose I have a TextBox in my DataGridCell.  After I call `grd.BeginEdit(e)`, I want the TextBox in that cell to have focus.  How can I do that?  I tried calling `FindName("txtBox")` on both the DataGridCell and the DataGrid, but it returns null for me.

Comment: GotFocus="DataGrid_GotFocus" seems to be missing?

Comment: This works well, but I would not recommend to do this. I have used this in my project and decided to rollback to standard DG behavior. In future, when your DG will grow and become complex, you will get issues with validation, adding new rows and other strange behavior.

Comment: @white.zaz was client happy after you made rollback to standard DG behavior? Because the main reason asking this question was that editing in standard DG capabilities is not user friendly as it needs too many times to be clicked before DG comes to Edit mode.

Comment: @AEMLoviji I would say yes but I'm not sure: it was 3 years ago :)

Comment: Thanks man, solved a lot of problem in grid and works way better than the stock grid.

Comment: There is one serious problem with this approach, this is resetting all my selected value in combobox while i try to sort the column !

Answer (score 45):

The answer from Micael Bergeron was a good start for me to find a solution thats working for me. To allow single-click editing also for Cells in the same row thats already in edit mode i had to adjust it a bit. Using SelectionUnit Cell was no option for me.

Instead of using the DataGridCell.Selected Event which is only fired for the first time a row's cell is clicked, i used the DataGridCell.GotFocus Event.

```
<DataGrid DataGridCell.GotFocus="DataGrid_CellGotFocus" />
```

If you do so you will have always the correct cell focused and in edit mode, but no control in the cell will be focused, this i solved like this

```
private void DataGrid_CellGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Lookup for the source to be DataGridCell
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
    {
        // Starts the Edit on the row;
        DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
        grd.BeginEdit(e);

        Control control = GetFirstChildByType<Control>(e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell);
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Focus();
        }
    }
}

private T GetFirstChildByType<T>(DependencyObject prop) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(prop); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((prop), i) as DependencyObject;
        if (child == null)
            continue;

        T castedProp = child as T;
        if (castedProp != null)
            return castedProp;

        castedProp = GetFirstChildByType<T>(child);

        if (castedProp != null)
            return castedProp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: checkboxes doesnt seem to work for me? i still have to doubleclick them

Comment: This helped me a lot.  The original datagrid is really difficult to work with.

Answer (score 9):

From: http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing

**XAML:**

```
<!-- SINGLE CLICK EDITING -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
</Style>
```

**CODE-BEHIND:**

```
//
// SINGLE CLICK EDITING
//
private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
    {
        if (!cell.IsFocused)
        {
            cell.Focus();
        }
        DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
            {
                if (!cell.IsSelected)
                    cell.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
                if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
                {
                    row.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
{
    UIElement parent = element;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
        if (correctlyTyped != null)
        {
            return correctlyTyped;
        }

        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work in certain cases, and its more complicated then Micael Bergerons solution.

Comment: For me, this almost was the solution. I needed to add a "PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" event handler and put there exactly the same code.

Comment: this doesn't work once you have a combobox either.  the preview click sees clicks on the combobox's popup, then the cell.focus call screws everything up.  easiest fix is to add a section that looks at the mouse events original source, using FindVisualParent on that to see if it is inside the datagrid.  if not, don't do any of the other work.

Answer (score 7):

The solution from http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing worked great for me, but I enabled it for every DataGrid using a Style defined in a ResourceDictionary. To use handlers in resource dictionaries you need to add a code-behind file to it. Here's how you do it:

This is a *DataGridStyles.xaml* Resource Dictionary:

```xml
    <ResourceDictionary x:Class="YourNamespace.DataGridStyles"
                x:ClassModifier="public"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <!-- Your DataGrid style definition goes here -->

            <!-- Cell style -->
            <Setter Property="CellStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">                    
                        <!-- Your DataGrid Cell style definition goes here -->
                        <!-- Single Click Editing -->
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                 Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Note the x:Class attribute in the root element. 
Create a class file. In this example it'd be *DataGridStyles.xaml.cs*. Put this code inside:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    partial class DataGridStyles : ResourceDictionary
    {

        public DataGridStyles()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
        }

     // The code from the myermian's answer goes here.
}
```

Comment: link is dead (15 character limit)

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by adding a trigger that sets IsEditing property of the DataGridCell  to True when the mouse is over it. It solved most of my problems. It works with comboboxes too.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: Doesn't work... it looses the edit as soon as the mouse leaves the cell. So you 1) left click on the cell you want to edit. 2) move the mouse out of the way 3) Start typing. Your typing doesnt work because the cell is no longer in edit mode.

Comment: doesnt work for me either. prevents editing textbox for me

Comment: But there is one problem with this approach,
I had locked the 1st column for editing, with this approach, this is making the 1st column also editable !

Answer (score 5):

i prefer this way based on Dušan Knežević suggestion. you click an that's it ))

```
<DataGrid.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsReadOnly"
                                   Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="IsEditing"
                                Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if a combobox is used as an editing template, I would assume others like check box that capture mouse events would break also

Comment: For me this works with combobox Columns, but the Textbox of the "new Item Line" (last line) has a strange behaviour: At first click I get the Input focus and can type stuff in. When i move the mouse out of the cell, the value of the textbox vanishes. When typing further, the newly entered Text is saved correctly(it creates a new entry as wished). This occurs even with a ComboboxColumn, too.

Comment: Initially seems like working fine, but totally messed up my Datagrid, when i try to sort, all these values are vanished, without this code everything works fine with sorting.

Comment: also the row validation doesn't trigger anymore

Answer (score 3):

I looking for editing cell on single click in MVVM and this is an other way to do it.

1. Adding behavior in xaml

   ```
   <UserControl xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                xmlns:myBehavior="clr-namespace:My.Namespace.To.Behavior">

       <DataGrid>
           <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
               <myBehavior:EditCellOnSingleClickBehavior/>
           </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       </DataGrid>
   </UserControl>
   ```
2. The EditCellOnSingleClickBehavior class extend System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior;

   ```
   public class EditCellOnSingleClick : Behavior<DataGrid>
   {
       protected override void OnAttached()
       {
           base.OnAttached();
           this.AssociatedObject.LoadingRow += this.OnLoadingRow;
           this.AssociatedObject.UnloadingRow += this.OnUnloading;
       }

       protected override void OnDetaching()
       {
           base.OnDetaching();
           this.AssociatedObject.LoadingRow -= this.OnLoadingRow;
           this.AssociatedObject.UnloadingRow -= this.OnUnloading;
       }

       private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
       {
           e.Row.GotFocus += this.OnGotFocus;
       }

       private void OnUnloading(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
       {
           e.Row.GotFocus -= this.OnGotFocus;
       }

       private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           this.AssociatedObject.BeginEdit(e);
       }
   }
   ```

Voila !

Comment: This was a great solution for my usecase but I did modify the `OnGotFocus` since otherwise, clicking Enter on the cell was triggering this method again and not committing the edit:
`var row = sender as Row; if (!row.IsEditing) this.AssociatedObject.BeginEdit(e);`

Answer (score 2):

I slightly edit solution from Dušan Knežević

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="ddlStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

and apply the style to my desire column

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource ddlStyle}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Several of these answers inspired me, as well as [this blog post](https://softwaremechanik.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/how-to-make-all-wpf-datagrid-cells-have-a-single-click-to-edit/), yet each answer left something wanting. I combined what seemed the best parts of them and came up with this *fairly* elegant solution that seems to get the user experience exactly right.

This uses some C# 9 syntax, which works fine everywhere though you may need to set this in your project file:

```
<LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
```

#### First, we get down from 3 clicks to 2 with this:

Add this class to your project:

```
public static class WpfHelpers
{
    internal static void DataGridPreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The original source for this was inspired by https://softwaremechanik.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/how-to-make-all-wpf-datagrid-cells-have-a-single-click-to-edit/
        DataGridCell? cell = e is MouseButtonEventArgs { OriginalSource: UIElement clickTarget } ? FindVisualParent<DataGridCell>(clickTarget) : null;
        if (cell is { IsEditing: false, IsReadOnly: false })
        {
            if (!cell.IsFocused)
            {
                cell.Focus();
            }

            if (FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell) is DataGrid dataGrid)
            {
                if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
                {
                    if (!cell.IsSelected)
                    {
                        cell.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell) is DataGridRow { IsSelected: false } row)
                    {
                        row.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal static T? GetFirstChildByType<T>(DependencyObject prop)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(prop);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(prop, i) is DependencyObject child)
            {
                T? typedChild = child as T ?? GetFirstChildByType<T>(child);
                if (typedChild is object)
                {
                    return typedChild;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static T? FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element)
        where T : UIElement
    {
        UIElement? parent = element;
        while (parent is object)
        {
            if (parent is T correctlyTyped)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Add this to your `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
        typeof(DataGrid),
        DataGrid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
        new RoutedEventHandler(WpfHelpers.DataGridPreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent));
}
```

#### Then we get from 2 to 1 with this:

Add this to the code behind of the page containing the `DataGrid`:

```
private void TransactionDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    WpfHelpers.GetFirstChildByType<Control>(e.EditingElement)?.Focus();
}
```

And wire it up (in XAML): `PreparingCellForEdit="TransactionDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit"`

Comment: This method works great until it meets template columns. Its behavior will be broken. It would not remove highlight on other rows before focusing on another row. Unfortunately I'm not good enough to understand why. But I think I have narrowed it down to a conclusion that this method somehow interferes with the way DataGrid handles focuses. Because if I don't let it focus on template columns, then it works fine.

Comment: I use templated columns almost exclusively and haven't had any problem like what you're describing.

Comment: That's strange. I hope I'm doing something wrong then. Because this solution is so elegant. I have created a small project to re-create the problem. I hope you can tell me what I did wrong. It's a simple DataGrid with 2 colums. A text column and a templated column containing 3 buttons. When the program starts, try focusing on the text column of the 2nd row, then click a button on the 1st row. You would see it highlights both rows.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLdK_Rq5hRrd-hv00AQivf2gyuysIOMH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmmm... I never tested with _buttons_ in my templated columns. I downloaded your code and you appear to have done all my steps right, and I see your grid behaves as intended for the first column. It's just the buttons that cause it to misbehave. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with user2134678's answer. One is very minor and has no functional effect. The other is fairly significant.

The first issueis that the GotFocus is actually being called against the DataGrid, not the DataGridCell in practice. The DataGridCell qualifier in the XAML is redundant.

The main problem I found with the answer is that the Enter key behavior is broken. Enter should move you to the next cell below the current cell in normal DataGrid behavior. However, what actually happens behind the scenes is GotFocus event will be called twice. Once upon the current cell losing focus, and once upon the new cell gaining focus. But as long as BeginEdit is called on that first cell, the next cell will never be activated. The upshot is that you have one-click editing, but anyone who isn't literally clicking on the grid is going to be inconvenienced, and a user-interface designer should not assume that all users are using mouses. (Keyboard users can sort of get around it by using Tab, but that still means they're jumping through hoops that they shouldn't need to.)

So the solution to this problem? Handle event KeyDown for the cell and if the Key is the Enter key, set a flag that stops BeginEdit from firing on the first cell. Now the Enter key behaves as it should.

To begin with, add the following Style to your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="SingleClickEditingCellStyle">
        <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="DataGridCell_KeyDown" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Apply that style to "CellStyle" property the columns for which you want to enable one-click.

Then in the code behind you have the following in your GotFocus handler (note that I'm using VB here because that's what our "one-click data grid requesting" client wanted as the development language):

```
Private _endEditing As Boolean = False

Private Sub DataGrid_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If Me._endEditing Then
        Me._endEditing = False
        Return
    End If

    Dim cell = TryCast(e.OriginalSource, DataGridCell)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    If cell.IsReadOnly Then
        Return
    End If

    DirectCast(sender, DataGrid).BeginEdit(e)
    .
    .
    .
```

Then you add your handler for the KeyDown event:

```
Private Sub DataGridCell_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
        Me._endEditing = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you have a DataGrid that hasn't changed any fundamental behavior of the out-of-the-box implementation and yet supports single-click editing.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

A simple solution if you are fine with that your cell stays a textbox (no distinguishing between edit and non-edit mode). This way single click editing works out of the box. This works with other elements like combobox and buttons as well. Otherwise use the solution below the update.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="My Column header">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty } />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

### Update end

I tried everything i found here and on google and even tried out creating my own versions. But every answer/solution worked mainly for textbox columns but didnt work with all other elements (checkboxes, comboboxes, buttons columns), or even broke those other element columns or had some other side effects. Because of that I decided to make a version which can be applied with a style to a textbox column directly without affecting other columns.

### Features

- No Code behind. MVVM friendly.
- It works when clicking on different textbox cells in the same or different rows.
- TAB and ENTER keys work.
- It doesnt affect other columns.

### Sources

I used this solution and @m-y's answer and modified them to be an attached behavior.
http://wpf-tutorial-net.blogspot.com/2016/05/wpf-datagrid-edit-cell-on-single-click.html

### How to use it

Add this Style.
The `BasedOn` is important when you use some [fancy styles](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) for your datagrid and you dont wanna lose them.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SingleClickEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextBoxSingleClickEditBehavior.Enable" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Apply the style with `CellStyle` to each of your `DataGridTextColumns` like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="My Header" Binding="{Binding Comment}" CellStyle="{StaticResource SingleClickEditStyle}" />         
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And now add this class to the same namespace as your MainViewModel (or a different Namespace. But then you will need to use a other namespace prefix than `local`). Welcome to the ugly boilerplate code world of attached behaviors.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace YourMainViewModelNameSpace
{
    public static class DataGridTextBoxSingleClickEditBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Enable",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(DataGridTextBoxSingleClickEditBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnableChanged));


        public static bool GetEnable(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            return (bool) frameworkElement.GetValue(EnableProperty);
        }


        public static void SetEnable(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, bool value)
        {
            frameworkElement.SetValue(EnableProperty, value);
        }


        private static void OnEnableChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is DataGridCell dataGridCell)
                dataGridCell.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }


        private static void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            EditCell(sender as DataGridCell, e);
        }

        private static void EditCell(DataGridCell dataGridCell, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridCell == null || dataGridCell.IsEditing || dataGridCell.IsReadOnly)
                return;

            if (dataGridCell.IsFocused == false)
                dataGridCell.Focus();

            var dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(dataGridCell);
            dataGrid?.BeginEdit(e);
        }


        private static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;

            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (parent is T parentWithCorrectType)
                    return parentWithCorrectType;

                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am a bit late to the party but I had the same problem and came up with a different solution:

```
     public class DataGridTextBoxColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
 {
  public DataGridTextBoxColumn():base()
  {
  }

  protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
  {
   throw new NotImplementedException("Should not be used.");
  }

  protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
  {
   var control = new TextBox();
   control.Style = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource("textBoxStyle");
   control.FontSize = 14;
   control.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(control, TextBox.TextProperty, Binding);
    control.IsReadOnly = IsReadOnly;
   return control;
  }
 }

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="exportData" Margin="15" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding CSVExportData}" Style="{StaticResource dataGridStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <local:DataGridTextBoxColumn Header="Sample ID" Binding="{Binding SampleID}" IsReadOnly="True"></local:DataGridTextBoxColumn>
            <local:DataGridTextBoxColumn Header="Analysis Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" IsReadOnly="True"></local:DataGridTextBoxColumn>
            <local:DataGridTextBoxColumn Header="Test" Binding="{Binding Test}" IsReadOnly="True"></local:DataGridTextBoxColumn>
            <local:DataGridTextBoxColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Comment}"></local:DataGridTextBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

As you can see I wrote my own DataGridTextColumn inheriting everything vom the DataGridBoundColumn. By overriding the GenerateElement Method and returning a Textbox control right there the Method for generating the Editing Element never gets called.
In a different project I used this to implement a Datepicker column, so this should work for checkboxes and comboboxes as well.

This does not seem to impact the rest of the datagrids behaviours..At least I haven't noticed any side effects nor have I got any negative feedback so far.

Answer (score -3):

```html
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" 
                            Value="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp] = [Action ReachThisMethod($source)]"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

```html
 public void ReachThisMethod(object sender)
 {
     ((System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell)(sender)).IsEditing = true;

 }
```