# How to make a DataGridCheckBoxColumn editable without requiring extra clicks?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, checkbox, edit

WPF's DataGrid requires a double click to enter cell editing mode, and then the user can change the checkbox value.

How to make a cell editable without requiring the double click for entering the edit mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wpf datagrid enter to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336868/wpf-datagrid-enter-to-edit)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just think of using a CheckBox directly in your CellTemplate.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Your boolean column">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YourBooleanProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: @XMLforDummies: Setting UpdateSourceTrigger is possible, but not really necessary in this case. It is more common if you are using a TextBox.

Comment: Actually, I was not able to get this to work without the UpdateSourceTrigger specification.

Comment: The above solution enables (de-)selecting checkbox with a single mouse click, but the column loses the ability to be selected by keyboard (space bar) :|