# Change cell value of selected item in datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

The datagrid is bound to a collectionview and the columns are not being auto generated. When the user selects a row in the datagrid, a code is generated. I want to insert this code in the Code column of the datagrid in WPF. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

OnClick using Grid.SelectedCell

Comment: Could you please provide a more elaborate answer?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @Liviu, That's not really what I want. That code just puts the row in edit mode. I don't need that. I want to know how a value can be (programmatically) inserted in a cel of the selected item.