# Datagrid not updating DataTable when applying a "single click" Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using a `Datagrid` and was asked to remove the annoying "double click" behavior of the Standard `DataGrid`, which contains a large number of autogenerated Checkbox-Columns.

I found this Style, which works well enough:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
</Trigger>
```

If used, only a single click is needed to edit the `Checkbox`.

Unfortunately, when this Style is used, the `Checkboxes` of the `DataGrid` are visually working, but the changes are not reflected in the `DataTable`.
This is probably due to the fact, that the cells are still in Editing Mode. **How can I circumvent this problem?**

I tried to simple force cells to finish editing when the mouse leaves, but that does not work:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="False" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to define your own cell template with a checkbox inside.

Source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1858654-26bd-4050-a1be-1f5d0209b1fe/how-do-i-change-a-datagrid-checkbox-without-clicking-twice

Comment: Nice work from Microsoft, but thanks!
Do you know if I can still use the Autogenerated Columns for this, or do I have to build them explicit?

Comment: Someone else may know ;)