# WPF DataGrid, DatePicker in template column, setting focus on textbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datepicker, datatemplate

Given a datagrid which contains a column with a DatePicker in the edit template, I would like to know if it's possible or how to set focus into the textbox portion of the control when the cell gets focus.  When running the code below, notice how clicking on the date column takes several clicks to get into the text box...the first click sets focus to the row, the second click gets the date column into edit mode, but I have to click again to get focus into the textbox.  I want to click once, or at the very least when the cell is clicked into edit mode, have the cursor in the textbox part ready for data entry.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MockGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MockData}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RowId" Binding="{Binding RowId}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowDate, StringFormat={}{0:d}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding RowDate}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And the corresponding code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MockData
    {
        public int RowId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RowDate { get; set; }
    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MockData> MockData { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (o, e) =>
        {
            MockGrid.DataContext = this;
            MockData = new ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.MockData>
            {
                new MockData { RowId = 1, RowDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1) },
                new MockData { RowId = 2, RowDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 2) }
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, that is exactly what I needed.  In case anyone else is looking for the same solution, the answer posted by user2134678 was specifically what solved it for me.