# WPF DataGridCell of wrong type

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid that isn't behaving. When I click to edit the cell, the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate is not displayed. If I click inside the cell and hit F2 to edit, the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate is displayed as it should be. I was trying to make this a one click edit cell using the code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid).

```
    private void PendingDetailsDataGrid_GotFocus( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof( DataGridCell ) )
        {
            DataGrid grd = ( DataGrid ) sender;
            grd.BeginEdit( e );
        }
    }
```

and I noticed that the if statement always fails because DataGridCell is of type Microsoft.Windows.Controls using assembly (WPFToolkit.dll) and the e.OriginalSource is of type System.Windows.Controls (Presentation.dll). If I hover over the DataGrid declaration in XAML view it shows System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid so how is the DataGridCell of the wrong type? I have an almost identical setup in another Window and I copied the DataGrid and the references from that form but nothing changed.

EDIT

```
<Controls:MetroWindow 
    x:Class="DFTI.Views.TransactionsWindow2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"    
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DFTI.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DFTI.Views"    
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
    xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
    Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
    Title="Transactions" Height="560" Width="900" 
    Name="Transactions"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ClosingCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                          x:Name="PendingTransactions"  
                          DataGridCell.Selected="PendingDetailsDataGrid_GotFocus" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding PendingTransactions}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding PendingDetails}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
                          Margin="10,0,10,17" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Posting Date" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding PostingDate}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Batch No" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding BatchNo}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>

                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                          Height="200"                           
                          ItemsSource="{Binding PendingDetails.Details}" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="True"
                          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
                          CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
                          DataGridCell.Selected="PendingDetailsDataGrid_GotFocus"
                          Margin="10,0">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="AccountNum" Header="Account No" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Path=Account.RawAccountNumber}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox 
                                            Background="AliceBlue"
                                            IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                            FilterMode="Contains"
                                            MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                            ValueMemberPath="RawAccountNumber"
                                            PreviewTextInput="AutoCompleteBox_PreviewTextInput"
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding Account, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            Text="{Binding Path=Account.RawAccountNumber}"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Accounts}" >
                                            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RawAccountNumber}" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DebitAmt" Header="Debit">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding DAmount, StringFormat='$#,##0.00;$(#,##0.00)'}" 
                                             Width="100"
                                             BorderThickness="0">
                                    </TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Controls:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding DAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" StringFormat="C2" Minimum="0" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="CreditAmt" Header="Credit">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding CAmount, StringFormat='$#,##0.00;$(#,##0.00)'}" 
                                             Width="100"
                                             BorderThickness="0">
                                    </TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Controls:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding CAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" StringFormat="C2" Minimum="0" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow >
```

Comment: The control which you found is the base editor used for the data. You can use Snoop WPF to estimate the tree. If you search up the Visual Tree you should find the DataGridCell which you then can set to BeginEdit() (eg. VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement). Sadly could not replicate due to you posted to less code.

Comment: Thanks @dsdel I will explore that. Any idea why it would work fine in another window in the same application? Also, since CodePlex is dead, where do you download Snoop WPF from?

Comment: Would need to take a look at the whole code. Perhaps some different styles/datatemplates? [Snoop Download link](http://www.cplotts.com/2017/10/27/snoop-2-8-0-download/) - as an alternative there is a Visual Browser built in in VS 2017

Comment: Thanks @dsdel I updated the question with the full code for my window. There are two DataGrids in the window, one is the parent the other is the child. It is the templates in the child grid that are not behaving.

Comment: you are using templates in the 2cond one. Tried my solution? And please check with Snoop - visualizing what is happening is sometimes more easiert to deal with : ) By using a template an additional visual is created in the layer to serve this custom template.

Answer (score 0):

Trt to use the fully qualified type name in the `if` statement. You should not need to involve `WPFToolkit.dll` here. This works for me:

```
private void PendingDetailsDataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell))
    {
        DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
        grd.BeginEdit(e);
    }
}
```