# WPF DataGrid - How to automatically set EditMode on a newly added row?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a program which so far follows MVVM principles/rules with 0 code behind and I have a DataGrid where users can add, edit or delete rows which represent students.
A user can add a row to the list by clicking on a "+" button but in order to edit the row the user has to first click on the row he just added which isn't so user-friendly.

I have been trying to set the newly added row in EditMode for a good while but all my attempts either failed or worked but with some disturbing side effects on the rest of the program. I looked it up online and the solutions I found either look like overkill or also have a bad side effect.

I created a similar program with less code to make it easier to show the structure of my program and DataGrid:

### Model

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
public class StudentsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public StudentsViewModel()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Student> students;
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get { return students; }
        set
        {
            students = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Students));
        }
    }

    private Student selectedStudent;
    public Student SelectedStudent
    {
        get { return selectedStudent; }
        set
        {
            selectedStudent = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedStudent));
        }
    }

    private ICommand addRow;
    public ICommand AddRow
    {
        get
        {
            if(addRow == null)
            {
                addRow = new RelayCommand(
                    parameter => AddStudent(new Student()),
                    parameter => true
                );
            }
            return addRow;
        }
    }

    private ICommand removeCmd;
    public ICommand RemoveCmd
    {
        get
        {
            removeCmd = new RelayCommand(
                parameter => RemoveStudent(parameter as Student),
                parameter => parameter != null
            );
            return removeCmd;
        }
    }

    private void AddStudent(Student studentToAdd)
    {
        Students.Add(studentToAdd);
    }

    private void RemoveStudent(Student studentToRemove)
    {
        if (Students.Contains(studentToRemove))
        {
            Students.Remove(studentToRemove);
        }
    }

    #region INotify

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

### View

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="600"
        Width="1000">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StudentsViewModel x:Key="StudentsVm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource StudentsVm}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False"
                   Background="#FF2C58EC">
            <Button Command="{Binding AddRow}"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="5">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/Images/AddItem.png"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding RemoveCmd}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=StudentDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="5">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/Images/DeleteItem.png"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource StudentsVm}, Path=SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  x:Name="StudentDataGrid"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                    Header="First Name">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                    Header="Last Name">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date of Birth">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateOfBirth, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                        DisplayDate="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                            </DatePicker>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                    Header="Phone Number">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                    Header="Address">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                    Header="Email">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would prefer the solution to be MVVM compatible but honestly at this point I would be satisfied as long as it doesn't cause other problems and doesn't require tons of frameworks or multiples files full of code.

I would prefer the result to look like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNBXZ.png) but [this is also acceptable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6MwA.png) as long as no mouse movement is involved after the "+" button click.

Comment: Your add button should bind to the ViewModel and not the Control that binds to the view model, that's first thing, I always cringe when I see names on UI elements. I am guessing that you don't want to show changes from your Model(student) as there is no INPC? And have you seen [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39681650/2029607)?

Comment: Do you mean the command parameter for the add button? The result is the same as far as I see, is this some sort of bad practice? I have less than a year of experience in WPF so excuse me when I ask this but what is so bad about naming UI elements if you bind to them? Also my model doesn't really need INPC (at least in this example) because it's only bound to an item source - my ObservableCollection which updates changes in the collection to the UI.

Comment: @XAMIMAX The answer you linked is quite different from what I want, I don't need single-click editing, especially one which has a disturbing side effect (read that answer's comment), what I want is the row to be selected and editable immediately after being added without having to click on it.

Comment: The idea behind that answer is to give you an indication on how you can achieve this. What you would do is to use `DataTrigger` instead of click, then Bind it to property on your student class that would indicate a new record (maybe ID that is 0). Does that makes sense?

Comment: @XAMIMAX I tried what you suggested and added ID property to Student in order to test this out but it didn't work, or at least only setting IsEditing to True is not enough to get it done

Comment: Why don't you use the default way of adding new items - empty bottom row? You can enable this by setting `CanUserAddRows="True"` on the DataGrid. When you edit the row, it becomes a regular row and new empty row appears at the bottom.

Comment: @Adam Štafa the users of my application are used to first add a row by clicking on a button and don't want an empty row at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what you want but it doesn't seem very robust so use with care. First, you should hookup to the `LoadingRow` event of your `DataGrid`.

**XAML**

```xml
<DataGrid ...
          LoadingRow="StudentDataGrid_LoadingRow"
          ...>
```

**Code-behind**

```cs
private async void StudentDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) {
    // Force asynchrony to run callback after UI has finished loading.
    await Task.Yield();
    // Mark the new row as selected
    StudentDataGrid.SelectedItem = e.Row.Item;
    StudentDataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(e.Row.Item, StudentDataGrid.Columns[0]);
    // Enter edit mode
    StudentDataGrid.BeginEdit();
}
```

By making the method `async` and by forcing it to execute asynchronously through the `await Task.Yield()` call, you let the UI finish the loading of the row before asking it to start an edit through the `BeginEdit()` call.

I'm writing this more as an experiment and I don't know if I would recommend this but I hope it helps while someone finds a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems to be working without a problem to me. Will use this for now unless I find a better answer. If I won't find anything better then I will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this (in code-behind, this behavior is completely view dependent):

```
void ButtonNew_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.LoadingRow += DataGridOnLoadingRow;
    var student = new Student();        
    ViewModel.Students.Add(student);
}

void DataGridOnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.LoadingRow -= DataGridOnLoadingRow;
    e.Row.Loaded += DataGridOnRowLoaded;
}

void DataGridOnRowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (DataGridRow)sender;
    row.Loaded -= DataGridOnRowLoaded;
    DataGridCell? cell = dataGrid!.GetCellOrDefault(row, column: 0);
    if (cell != null)
    {
        dataGrid!.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
        dataGrid.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

In fact, I use the `LoadingRow` event to get a reference to the row and then I add an handler on the row `Loaded` event. This way, I'm sure that the row (and the cell) is loaded when I set the cell as current and when I call `BeginEdit()`.

To get the cell I use this extension method:

```
static class DataGridExtensions
{
    internal static DataGridCell? GetCellOrDefault(this DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow row, int column)
    {   
        DataGridCellsPresenter? presenter = FindVisualChildOrDefault<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        if (presenter == null)
        {
            row.ApplyTemplate();
            presenter = FindVisualChildOrDefault<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        }

        if (presenter != null)
        {
            if (presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) is DataGridCell cell)
                return cell;
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(row, dataGrid.Columns[column]!);
            return presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
        }

        return null;
    }

    static T? FindVisualChildOrDefault<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {    
        for (int i = 0; i < System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child is T visualChild)
                return visualChild;
            T? childOfChild = FindVisualChildOrDefault<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```