# WPF DataGrid single click CheckBox does not enter Edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with `CheckBox`-type column which should be editable with single click. This is easily achieved by [using template column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7270548/3096657) with `CheckBox` inside:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox BackGround="Red" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

the problem, however, is that single clicking will change the value without ever entering Edit mode. How can I ensure the edit mode is entered before changing the CheckBox value (all will single click)?

---

My best attempt on the problem was setting `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` on `DataGridCell` through style and forcing `BeginEdit()`. While this does begin edit, it is back to needing double click to interact.

```
private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DataGridCell cell && !cell.IsEditing && e.OriginalSource is DependencyObject source)
    {
        var checkBoxParent = VisualExtensions.GetVisualParent<CheckBox>(source);
        if (checkBoxParent != null) // ensure CheckBox was clicked
        {
            cell.Focus();
            ItemListDG.BeginEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried handling `Selected` or `GotFocus` without any luck (breaks other types of interaction), `CheckBox.Checked` events cannot be used neither because they trigger on re/load.

---

In case of `Selected` event, the problem is that it enables single click edit on all columns even though it is handled on just one column (again, set through style):

```
private void DataGridCell_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // second part of condition is always true, no matter what cell is clicked
    if (sender is DataGridCell cell && cell.Column == ItemListDG.Columns[0])
    {
        // try to detect if the CheckBox column was clicked, if not return
        if (sender != e.OriginalSource) // always false
            return;

        ItemListDG.BeginEdit(e); // always executes no matter the source
    }
}
```

Comment: The control in the `CellTemplate` is not visibile when you're in edit mode. This is supposed to be a read-only control. Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid)?

Comment: @mm8 yes, I have seen it and tried handling `Selected` event, it breaks other types of interaction. In the case of `Selected` it is global, even if you attach it to just one column, it fires when clicking other columns as well, causing single click edit on every single one column.

Comment: You could determine which column is clicked using the `Column` property of the `DataGridCell`.

Comment: @mm8 that was one of my ideas as well, turns out the event args do not have the actual Source/OriginalSource/sender information, all three are set to the `DataGridCell` on which `Selected` is attached on, regardless what cell was clicked.

Comment: `DataGridCell` is the cell that was clicked, isn't it? Please provide an example of where you failed.

Comment: @mm8 sure, got a bunch more failed attempts, added the one with `Selected` with annotations.

Comment: So why don't you use the `Column` property as I suggested? `sender is DataGridCell cell && cell.Column == yourColumn...`

Comment: @mm8 let me rephrase, the cell of `Selected` event is not being set by WPF correctly. No matter what, it is the cell the event is on, not the actually selected/clicked cell. The `sender is DataGridCell cell && cell.Column == yourColumn` always evaluates to `true`,

Comment: No, it doesn't. What is `yourcolumn` in your case?

Comment: @mm8 first column (`ItemListDG.Columns[0]`), updated the sample with the column comparison code. It is always true, always edits on click, the event is attached only on the first column cells.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224369/discussion-between-wondra-and-mm8).

Answer (score 0):

The event which should be handled is `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`, same like the case with Down event, after `BeginEdit()` is called the original `CheckBox` does not exist anymore and cannot handle the un/checking. The solution to doubleclick problem is to find the new representation of the CheckBox and either re-raise the event threre or toggle it manually:

```
private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DataGridCell cell && !cell.IsEditing && e.OriginalSource is UIElement source)
    {
        var actualSource = source is CheckBox ? 
            (CheckBox)source : VisualExtensions.GetVisualParent<CheckBox>(source);

        if (actualSource != null)
        {
            ItemListDG.BeginEdit();

            var newSource = cell.GetVisualChild<CheckBox>();
            if (newSource != null)
            {
                newSource.IsChecked = !newSource.IsChecked;
            }
        }      

    }
}
```